# Can I add multiple Test Methods in .cs in Coded UI

Tags: coded-ui-tests, testautomationfx

Can I add multiple test methods in one .cs file in code UI.

Below is my code. I have two features. 1. Login and Log off.

I have created one CodedUITest1.cs file where i an trying to add multiple methods. Is it really possible to do that

public class CodedUITest1
    {
        public CodedUITest1()
        {
        }

```
    [TestMethod]
    public void Login()
    {
        this.UIMap.Login();
        this.UIMap.Assert_Login();
        this.UIMap.LogOff();
    }

    [TestMethod]
    public void LogOff()
    {
       this.UIMap.LogOff();
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can have multiple tests in a test class.  What is the problem you are noticing?

Normally, I use the TestInitialize attribute to setup the common steps for all tests and then each test method does something different from that point and performs assertions, etc.

```
public class LoginPageTests
{
    BrowserWindow bw;
    [TestInitialize]
    public void GivenLoginPage()
    {
        bw = BrowserWindow.Launch("http://yoursite.com/loginPage");
    }

    [TestMethod]
    public void WhenSupplyingValidCredentials_ThenLoginSucceedsAndAccountsPageIsShown()
    {
        Assert.IsTrue(bw.Titles.Any(x => "Login"));
        HtmlEdit userNameEdit = new HtmlEdit(bw);
        userNameEdit.SearchProperties.Add("id", "userName");
        userNameEdit.Text = "MyUserName";

        HtmlEdit passEdit = new HtmlEdit(bw);
        passEdit.SearchProperties.Add("id", "pass");
        passEdit.Text = "MyPassword";

        HtmlButton loginButton = new HtmlButton(bw);
        Mouse.Click(loginButton);

        // probably can one of the WaitFor* methods to wait for the page to load
        Assert.IsTrue(bw.Titles.Any(x => "Accounts"));
    }

    [TestMethod]
    public void WhenNoPassword_ThenButtonIsDisabled()
    {
        HtmlEdit userNameEdit = new HtmlEdit(bw);
        userNameEdit.SearchProperties.Add("id", "userName");
        userNameEdit.Text = "MyUserName";

        HtmlButton loginButton = new HtmlButton(bw);
        Assert.IsFalse(loginButton.Enabled);
    }
}
```